# Sum subarray's length

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking to count the unread messages in all conversations where a user is a member of the conversation. A message is read by a user if it's id is in the readers array.

The following returns the number of conversations where there exist unread messages. But how to count all unread messages?

```
db.getCollection('conversations').count({
    'messages.readers': { $size: 1 }, //i.e. only the message author is in the message.readers array.
    'members': { $in: [ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f")] }
})
```

I have checked the aggregate method but I'm not sure if it's the right approach. The following returns the number of all messages.

```
        db.getCollection('conversations').aggregate([
    {$match : {
        'members': { $in: [ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f")] }
     }},
    {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: {$size: "$messages"}}}}, 
])
```

[image]

Comment: You can use query to check if the user is in `members` array and user not in `messages.readers` array  followed by count. Something like `db.getCollection('conversations').count({'members': ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f"), "messages.readers" : { $ne: ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f") }})`

Comment: Of course, but that will count the number of conversations and not the number of unread messages.

Comment: I think I designed this database the wrong way.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really pay attention to all the different parts you have there. The below query will unwind each message in every matched conversation and apply the query filter. Something like `db.getCollection('conversations').aggregate([
    {$match : {'members': ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f") }},
  {$unwind:"$messages"}, 
    {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: {$cond: [{ $ne: ["messages.readers", ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f")] }, 1, 0]}}}} 
])`. I'm not able to test any queries because the data you posted is image. Please consider adding documents as text.

Comment: Works great Veeram. Cheers! Please post it as an aswers. The $unwind is a great function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation pipeline.

The below query will `$unwind` all messages in every matched conversation and apply the `$cond` expression inside of `$sum` operator to check if the user is not in `messages.readers` and return 1 if there is a match or else 0 in a `$group` stage.

```
db.getCollection('conversations').aggregate([ 
  {$match : {'members': ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f") }}, 
  {$unwind : "$messages"}, 
  {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: {$cond: [{ $ne: ["messages.readers", ObjectId("59320e38188c5050ac99be8f")] }, 1, 0]}}}} 
])
```

As such, `$unwind`is an expensive operation and should not be preferred over other options, but I don't think in your case it is possible and `$unwind` following `$match` is little better.